# Convert Address to long - variable results in value?

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers, variadic-functions

Can anybody explain this behaviour to me pls?

```
static short nDoSomething(const char* pcMsg, ...)
{
  va_list pvArgument;
  long lTest;
  void* pvTest = NULL;

  va_start(pvArgument, pcMsg);

  pvTest = va_arg(pvArgument, void*);
  lTest  = (long) pvTest;

  va_end(pvArgument);
  return 0;
}
```

If I call this function in the main like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   char acTest1[20];
   nDoSomething("TestMessage", 1234567L, acTest1);


  return 0;
}
```

I thought that the address of pvTest would be in lTest, but in fact it contains 1234567 ...

How is this possible?

Comment: When you say the address _of_ `pvTest`, you mean: the address `pvTest` is pointing to, right? And you are confused why _that_ is `1234567`, correct?

Comment: To get the address of `pvTest`, you have to take its address: `(long)&pvText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains undefined behavior; the standard requires
that the type extracted using `va_arg` correspond to the type
passed (modulo cv-qualifiers, perhaps): You passed a `long`, and
read a `void*`, so anything which the compiler does is correct.

In practice, most compilers generate code which does no type
checking.  If on your machine, `long` and `void*` have the same
size (and the machine has linear addressing), you will probably
end up with whatever you passed as `long`.  If the sizes of the
two are different, but the machine is little endian, and you
pass a small enough value, you might end up with the same value
as well.  But this is not at all guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You are just lucky here.

```
va_start(pvArgument, pcMsg);
```

prepares for `va_arg(pvArgument,T)` to extract the next variable
argument following `pcMsg` with the presumption that it is of type `T`.

The next argument after `pcMsg` is in fact the `long int 1234567`; but
you wrongly extract it as a `void *` and then cast it to `long` into
`lTest`. You are just lucky that a `void *` on your system is the
same size as a `long`.

(Or maybe I mean *oddly unlucky*)